# Can I map svn externals with subgit?

Tags: git-svn, subgit

I am working  with subgit and I don't understand well how it deals with svn externals. I found this in [the help](https://subgit.com/documentation/config-options.html#translate)

> [translate]
>
> externals = [true|false]
>
> a boolean value, can be set to true or false. SubGit does not support translating svn:externals to Git submodules and back. However,
>   when this option is set to true, SubGit creates special
>   .gitsvnextmodules files in the root of every Git commit; these files
>   store information on all the svn:externals definitions found in a
>   given SVN branch. When false, SubGit ignores any svn:externals
>   properties. Default is false.

Does this mean that the externals are not processed at all but just logged into a file so that you are aware of?

Could I create a hook with subgit to the external repo and make that new git repo as a sub-module for git ?

THanks in advance,

Answer (score 1):

That's right, SubGit doesn't create neither submodules, nor subtrees out of SVN externals. If svn.externals is set to 'true', then SubGit indeed just logs the SVN externals definitions to .gitsvnextmodules file and nothing more.
Probably it's possible to create a script that would create submodules, but I'm not aware or ready solutions for that and there's no such feature in SubGit.